# Unexpected Crash on iPhone X on launching the application

Tags: objective-c, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

Application is working fine on all devices including iPhone 8 except iPhone X.
Scenario  is setting a viewcontrooller as the topviewcontroller on Push of navigation system and removing them on pop of navigation controller system. On launching on iPhoneX it crashes with the following error. This is the Push Method.

```
 - (void)pushViewController:(MTRViewController *)viewControler {
        self.viewControllers = [self.viewControllers arrayByAddingObject:vc];
        viewControler.navigationController = self;
        self.topViewController = viewControler;
        }
```

This is the error log.

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MTRWindowViewController _isLayingOutTopViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa629c11d50'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: It might be a case of not having `_isLayingOutTopViewController` properly referenced to the UI ViewController...

Comment: @l'L'l but it is working on all other devices

Comment: @l'L'l Any suggestion for fixing this? All of my viewcontrollers are subclass of a custom UIViewcontroller

Comment: Not really, it's odd that the issue is only happening on `iPhone X`, which I haven't yet worked with unfortunately...